# How to parameterize the tasks enabled attribute in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

With latest SonarCloud outage, I decided I am finally ready to add a true/false flag to the SonarCloud tasks in my pipelines. So I am checking to see if its possible to put a check in the `enabled:` attribute where I pass in a variable like `IsSonarEnabled` which would be true or false.

Thanks,
Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to do this, but not via the `enabled:` attribute, and not directly with the variable value.

First of all I had to use `condition:` as I don't think `enabled:` was going to play nice with runtime variables.

Additionally I decided to use a global variable as I have 12 pipelines, and in my case, my usecase for shutting sonarcloud off is only during an outage, so I didn't have much use for putting the parameter in the individual pipelines. So I added a Variable Group - **FeatureFlags** to my Library and added the variable `IsSonarEnabled_Global` and referenced it in my pipeline YML as such.

```
  variables:
  - group: FeatureFlags
```

Also I found out that the variables evaluate to strings, so I had to do a string comparison instead, so I used
`eq(variables.IsSonarEnabled_Global, 'true')`

In the end my pipeline looked something like this

```
trigger: 
  tags:
    include: 
    - dev1000

jobs:

- job: Build
  timeoutInMinutes: 120

  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  variables:
  - group: FeatureFlags

  steps:

  - task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
    condition: eq(variables.IsSonarEnabled_Global, 'true')
    ## stripped for brevity ##
    
  - task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
    condition: eq(variables.IsSonarEnabled_Global, 'true')

  - task: SonarCloudPublish@1
    condition: eq(variables.IsSonarEnabled_Global, 'true')
    inputs:
      pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Not sure if it is in here but one thought too if using global variables is to define them using a [variable template file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse).  That way it is decoupled and can be re used in additional repos

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: thanks Devin! This is exaclty what I need and thought of the 'enabled' property at first but it does not work at runtime indeed.